# For loop sequencing using modulo

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm kind of new to programming, just started learning python, and don't have a lot of experience with the modulo operator. I would like to enter a certain amount of seconds into the terminal to count down from using the for loop. After every ten seconds, I would like label one to be printed. After label one is printed, I would like label two to be printed two seconds later. The pattern should continue in that order until all the time has run out. I tried many different things to get this to work and feel I'm missing something simple. When I get rid of label two and run the code, I can set label one to print every ten seconds or thirteen seconds if I want. With that being said, I feel label one is somehow throwing off label two and I need to perform some kind of math for label two to fire two seconds after label one or somehow I need to set label two to zero so after it counts up to twelve it will stop and start over without adding an additional two seconds? Also, I am planning to add other labels to repeat after a certain amount of seconds or iterations, but figured I would start with just two first to keep it simple.

```
import time

seconds = int(input("\n\n\tEnter Seconds: "))

for i in range(seconds):
    print ("\n\t" + (str(seconds - i)))
    time.sleep(1)

    if (i % 10 == 0):
        print ("\t\t\tShow Label 1")
        print (i)

    if (i % 12 == 0):
        print ("\t\t\tShow Label 2")
        print (i)
```

Comment: fix indentation please, the code you've provided here won't compile

Comment: do you have some requirement to use `time.sleep` rather than processing against the system time in a `while` loop?

Answer (score 3):

As currently written (if you fix the indentation), label 1 will print on 0, 10, 20, 30… and label 2 will print on 0, 12, 24, 36…. In other words, the thing on the right side of the `%` is how often it repeats.

It sounds like you want label 2 to also print every ten seconds, but delayed by two. In that case, you still need a ten on the right side of the `%`, since it repeats every ten seconds. Just change what you're comparing it against:

```
if i%10 == 2:
```

You can think of this as running "on step #2 of the ten-step cycle". Another way to visualize the modulus operator is by looking at a clock face: "1:00" means `hours%12 == 1`, and "3:00" means `hours%12 == 3`.

Comment: Ha, I knew it was something simple I wasn't seeing thanks a lot.